# webpack-dev-server dynamic port

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Is it possible to find a unused port for webpack-dev-server?
My current configuration does look like:

```
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    inline: true,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 3000,
    contentBase: helpers.root('public'),
    stats: 'minimal'
}
```

Comment: What is your problem? The dev server won't run on port 3000?

Comment: I do run on port 3000. We are many developers and port 3000 ist in use by other developers sometimes. Can webpack-dev-server find a unused port like BrowserSync does?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When omitting `port`, `webpack-dev-server` uses the first available port starting with 8000, see [the PR](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/pull/685). Requiring `webpack-dev-server`⩾2.2.

For earlier versions, [the port 0 trick](https://www.dnorth.net/2012/03/17/the-port-0-trick/) could work. See [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/752) for details.

Answer (score 2):

If omitting `port` is not an option, you can use [portfinder-sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/portfinder-sync) to automatically select the next available port for you:

```js
const portFinderSync = require('portfinder-sync')

devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    inline: true,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: portFinderSync.getPort(3000),
    contentBase: helpers.root('public'),
    stats: 'minimal'
}
```

In my case, I couldn't omit `port` because I needed it to set `public` property in my `devServer` config:

```
const portFinderSync = require('portfinder-sync')
const port = portFinderSync.getPort(8080)

devServer: {
  contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
  host: '0.0.0.0',
  open: true,
  port: port,
  public: `${ipaddress}:${port}`,
},
```