# Playwright use dynamic port for devserver

Tags: javascript, webpack, playwright

Problem: When running playwright test in azure pipeline, The port 3000 is already in use sometimes(maybe other pipeline runs on the same azure agent)

I think instead of using another port like 3001 it would be better to assign the port automatically, meaning a free port will be choosen.

I looked at this [issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/issues/2051) but i dont want to modify my webpack config. Is there a way to configure this behaviour in the playwright config?

Here are the configs i refer to:

I have this entry in `playwright.config.ts`

```
 webServer: {
     command: 'npm run start',
     timeout: 120 * 1000,
     port: 3000
  },
```

And this webpack dev server configuration:

```
 devServer: {
     port: 3000,
     compress: true,
     open: true,
     watchFiles: 'src',
     historyApiFallback: true,
     client: {
        overlay: {
           errors: true,
           warnings: true,
            runtimeErrors: false,
        },
     },
 },
```

Comment: Omit port or use port 0: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42077022/11083750

Comment: I tried it out, a random port will be choosen. But the problem remains because the webserver config requires either a `port` or a `url` property. This means i should know the port/the url before starting the devserver which obviously is not the case